# Saving several images (and metadata for each) in a single file using Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, arrays

Is it possible, via Adobe Air, to save multiple types of data in a single file? For example, an application would allow the user to load in external images, position them on stage and label them. This data would be then be stored in a ByteArray (I guess) using BitmapData for the images and probably XML for the metadata.

I would then like to write this to a single file, with a bespoke file extension that could be associated with said Air app.

I've asked this on various forums and never received a single reply.

Comment: +1 I'll respond, if only to say it's a good question and I hope you get a satisfactory answer here, as well as to explain to American readers that "bespoke" means something like "custom-made" or "proprietary."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add everything to a byte array and write it to file - but defining boundaries and extracting individual entities back from the file would take some effort. How about writing them to normal files, zipping them to a single file and deleting the originals? This way you can still have a single file and deal with the individual items more easily.

This article describes some [ActionScript zip libraries](http://devlogs.heymath.com/2010/05/01/adobe-air-zip-libraries/).  I've used [nochump](http://nochump.com/blog/?p=15) in the past and it was easy - [this page has some sample code](http://pradeek.blogspot.com/2009/05/extracting-zip-files-in-adobe-air-with.html)

If you want some individuality for your files, you can rename the zipped file to whatever extension you want - that's what Firefox extensions do, they have `.xpi` extension, but they're plain zip files renamed.

Comment: Ok that does seem a much simpler way to do it, I shall look into it. In fact, effectively creating a .zip file makes things much easier for me in the long run. Thanks for your answer.